# Left join table with LIKE statement

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have two tables one is `order` and other `sales`

```
+-------------+
| OrderNumber |
+-------------+
|           1 |
|           2 |
+-------------+

+---------------+
|  SalesNumber  |
+---------------+
| /sales/1/lep  |
| /sales/test/2 |
+---------------+
```

So I want to use left join with this to tables with the number coincidence, so I think somethink like:

```
select * from order as o
left join sales as s on s.SalesNumber LIKE '%/'+o.OrderNumber+'%'
```

but if throw an error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '%' to data type
> int.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Since `OrderNumber` is an int, you'll need to `cast` it to a `varchar`.

Comment: Suggested reading: [Data Type Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). Aside: You probably want to add a trailing delimiter to both strings, e.g. `'/'`, to avoid matches like `1` in `'/sales/15/foo'`. Depending on the variety of string it may be needed at both ends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast the `OrderNumber` column as a `VARCHAR` and then do a `CONCAT` or `+` operation to form the combined string.

Try this:

```
select * from order as o
left join sales as s 
    on s.SalesNumber LIKE CONCAT('%/', CAST(o.OrderNumber AS VARCHAR),'%')
```

Let me know if that helps!

Comment: Is better use `CONCAT `than `+`? why?

Comment: @Leon thanks for the question!  I prefer to use ```CONCAT``` when combining strings since I think it's cleaner, but you can use either.  See this article here: http://www.dbafire.com/2015/07/09/what-is-the-difference-between-and-concat-function-in-sql/.

Comment: Actually, you DON'T need the cast in the concat()

Answer (score 3):

One advantage of `concat()` is you don't need conversion -- the function converts numbers to strings.  So:

```
on s.SalesNumber LIKE CONCAT('%/', o.OrderNumber, '%')
```

You can use `+`, but you have to convert to a string:

```
on s.SalesNumber like '%/' + convert(varchar(255), o.OrderNumber) + '%'
```

Note that there is a length on `varchar()`.  *Always* use lengths in SQL Server when you specify a string.  The default varies by context and might not do what you want.

Comment: Not clear on the requirements, but assuming order number is 1 then  /sales/1999/lep   would be picked up as well

Comment: @JohnCappelletti . . . This is based on the OP's attempt which doesn't work due to type conversion issues.

Comment: Thanks to clarify use of `CONCAT ` vs `+`

Comment: @GordonLinoff Absolutely agree, that is why I mentioned the fuzzy requirement.